# Having issue with pyaudio and sockets

Tags: python, sockets, record, pyaudio

I am trying to fix a script I wrote. It's a client application and I need to figure out how to use sockets to record data from a computer running linux in my office.

I am using netcat for the server, listening on port 5555.

I know I have to convert the `i` to a integer, but am having trouble.

I already have a ftp script for sending the .wav file I just need to get the `s.recv` prompt to work.

```
import pyaudio
import wave
from socket import*
s = socket()
host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 5555
s.connect((host,port))
s.send("how many seconds?\n")
i = s.recv(2)
CHUNK = 1024 
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16 #paInt8
CHANNELS = 2 
RATE = 44100 #sample rate
RECORD_SECONDS = i
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "output.wav"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
            channels=CHANNELS,
            rate=RATE,
            input=True,
            frames_per_buffer=CHUNK) #buffer

print("* recording")

frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
  data = stream.read(CHUNK)
  frames.append(data) # 2 bytes(16 bits) per channel

print("* done recording")

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()

wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(RATE)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
wf.close()
```

Comment: you define `i` as `i = s.recv(2)` and then redefine it in your `for` loop. Try `for _ in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):` instead.

Comment: i see what you are saying this is the error i get OverflowError: range() result has too many items Its the same error as before bit i did need to change that anyway i think its something to do with the i =s.recv() it has to be converted to a integer but even then it still does the same thing

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you rename `i` to `USER_INPUT` to prevent a name clash with the `for`-loop below. Then convert convert that value to an `int` using the in-built [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int), like so:

```
s.send("how many seconds?\n")
USER_INPUT = s.recv(2)
RECORD_SECONDS = int(USER_INPUT) # TODO: handle invalid user input
```

You could confirm this value has been converted, then:

```
s.send("Shall record for %d seconds\n" % RECORD_SECONDS)
```